# Почему не загружается Gdk::Pixbuf когда выполняю программу вне консоли msys2?

Tags: c++, msys2

```
auto img = Gtk::make_managed<Gtk::Image>();
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pbuf = nullptr;
try
{
    pbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_resource(<path_in_res>, 100, 100);
    img->set(pbuf);
}
catch (const Glib::FileError &e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
}
catch (const Gdk::PixbufError &e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Потому что в путях MSYS2 прописаны пути к библиотекам, а без, нет, вот вам и надо положить необходимые библиотеки в папку с программой, либо собрать со статическими библиотеками.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, библиотеки рядом положил. Суть в том, что pixbuf не загружается вне консоли. А так прога запускается.

Comment: Все правильно, потому что терминал msys добавлял пути к библиотекам за вас, для удобства, для распространения программы, необходимо распространять и библиотеки которые используются.

Comment: Все работает вне консоли! Только Gdk::Pixpuf вылетает и исключение не кидает. Причем в glade  файлах отрабатывает pixbuf  из ресурсов на отлично. А из кода, не работает! Вся программа работает без консоли msys2.

Comment: Все получилось! Копируешь папку gdk-pixbuf-2.0 в lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ рядом с exe файлом.